# Ubuntu MATE 19.10 mouse/touch pad not working on hp stream 14

Tags: mouse, touchpad, hp

I updated to Ubuntu Mate 19.10 on my HP Stream 14 and the mouse/touch pad didn't work, so I did a fresh install and it still doesn't work. A usb mouse works fine and as it should. I'm hoping someone may know a fix for this.

`xinput` output:

```
tweety@tweety-HP-Stream-Laptop-14-ax0XX:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer id=2 [master pointer (3)]
⎜ ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ Logitech Optical USB Mouse id=10 [slave pointer (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard id=5 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button id=6 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus id=7 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button id=8 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ HP Webcam: HP Webcam id=9 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard id=11 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ HP Wireless hotkeys id=12 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ HP WMI hotkeys id=13 [slave keyboard (3)]
tweety@tweety-HP-Stream-Laptop-14-ax0XX:~$
```

I don't think my touchpad is showing up at all. The logitech Optical USB Mouse is the USB mouse I'm using while I try to fix the touchpad...

Comment: I got this fixed using the following video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDtJooJJfFE

Answer (score 1):

I got this fixed using the following video:

youtube.com/watch?v=wDtJooJJfFE

Here is the written directions for the same video:

In this video I show you how to fix Touchpad mouse not working in linux operating systems. 
Hope this fix your problem.

Steps:

1. Enter in terminal type:

   sudo nano /etc/default/grub

In there you will enter this commands:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash psmouse.proto=bare"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
```

Next you are going to save the grub file by pressing:

```
  ctrl + o
```

an then exit the grub editor:

```
  ctrl + x
```

Now update the grub in terminal:

```
  sudo update-grub
```

When update finishes enter in terminal:

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
```

Then type and enter:

```
  sudo apt-get update
```

Now install a program call touchpad-indicator:

```
   sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

Thank you for watching !